# PLSQL - Procedure para Criptografar Senha

Tags: oracle, pl-sql, procedure

Procurei na internet uma procedure para **criptografar a senha dos usuários**, contudo apenas encontrei **functions**.

Há como gerar uma **procedure** para realizar este processo?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION MD5(VALOR VARCHAR) 
    RETURN VARCHAR2 
IS 
    V_INPUT VARCHAR2(2000) := VALOR; 
    HEXKEY  VARCHAR2(32)   := NULL; 
BEGIN 
    HEXKEY := RAWTOHEX(DBMS_OBFUSCATION_TOOLKIT.MD5(INPUT => UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW(V_INPUT))); 
    RETURN NVL(HEXKEY, ''); 
END;
```

Comment: Basta mudar a declaração para procedure e retirar o Return e utilizar o retorno do RAWTOHEX como você desejar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode alterar a função e transformá-la em uma procedure, mas recomendo que use a package DBMS_CRYPTO, ela substitui a DBMS_OBFUSCATION_TOOLKIT e fornece uma lista mais completa de algoritmos de criptografia.

Um ponto de atenção é que a package DBMS_CRYPTO não trabalha com VARCHAR2 diretamente, mas é possível converter um VARCHAR2 para RAW usando a  utl_i18n.string_to_raw.

Montei o exemplo a seguir, espero que atenda sua necessidade.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE md5 (
   p_txt    IN VARCHAR2,
   p_hash   OUT VARCHAR2
) AS
   v_hash_raw   RAW(32);
BEGIN
   --Calcular o hash usando o algoritmo MD5
   v_hash_raw := dbms_crypto.hash(src => utl_i18n.string_to_raw(p_txt,'AL32UTF8'),
                                  typ => dbms_crypto.hash_md5);

   --Converter RAW para exadecimal
   p_hash := rawtohex(v_hash_raw);
END md5;
```